# g++ fatal error: no input files windows

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, cmd

I'm trying to set windows programming enviroment for c++. I use the Visual Studio to write the code but my University wants me to use g++ compiler. So far I managed to link g++ with the PATH using cmd but that's not all. I have to use an alias which in linux is:

```
p1++="g++ -ansi -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wextra -Werror -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow
```

I tried the same using the command doskey:

```
doskey p1=g++ -ansi -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wextra -Werror -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow
```

and it works but whenever I use for example:

```
p1++ hello.cpp
```

it says

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

but if i use:

```
g++ hello.cc
```

It does compile, so my question is what does all that code mean and how can I get rid of that error?

Thanks

Comment: "hello.ccp"? Anyone know if GCC looks at file extensions?

Comment: @Mysticial: It does, yes. `g++` also adds some extra libraries to the link line.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah, what greyfade said, and furthermore if you try to compile a `.c` file with g++ it will compile it as C.

Comment: `cc` is fine, `cpp` is fine. `ccp` is not.

Comment: my bad sorry i meant cpp but i doesnt compile regardless of if it's cpp or cc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.cpp (assumed to exist at C:\test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; return 0; }
```

Here's what it looks like in my Windows CMD prompt:

NOTE: No quotes in alias, and it is assumed that `g++` is already in your `PATH`.

```
C:\>set p1++=g++ -ansi -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wextra -Werror -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow

C:\>%p1++%
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

C:\>%p1++% test.cpp

C:\>a.exe
hello

C:\>doskey p1++=%p1++% $*

C:\>p1++ test.cpp

C:\>a.exe
hello
```

If you wanted to have the `%p1++%` environment variable persist across CMD prompts then you'd need to add an environment variable to your Windows User Profile.

On Windows 7:

```
Control Panel => System => Advanced System Settings => Environment Variables.
```

Create a new User Variable with name = `p1++` and value = `g++ -ansi -Wall -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wextra -Werror -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow`.

Comment: ok that worked very well but why it is not working with the doskey command and is there a way to preserve that asignation so that i dont have to assing it every time i enter cmd

Comment: @Buradi - Doskey is a program, not an environmental variable, so it cannot preserve macros across different instances of CMD. What you need to do is create a shortcut to CMD.EXE, and then edit the `Target:` value under the `Shortcut` tab to read `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k doskey p1++=%p1++% $*`. Then instead of launching CMD.EXE, launch CMD.EXE.LNK, before you are given control doskey will be run and the macro created.